# Convert string to lowercase AND then convert it to its original form in PHP, is it possible?

Tags: php, string, api

I need to convert input data to lower and then return it in it's original form with PHP, is it impossible or does anyone have a solution? thank you.

ps, i'm sorry if there is another thread about this subject but i havn't found one.

```
function getdatalanguage($data){ 
    $data = replacequote($data); 
    $data = replacecolon($data); 
    $data = strtolower($data); 
    $startlang = "språk";
    $endlang = "datum";
    $datalang = getBetween($event1,$startlang,$endlang); 
    $startlang1 = ">"; 
    $endlang1 = "<"; 
    $datatlang = getBetween($datalang,$startlang1,$endlang1); 
    return $datalang; 
}
```

the data I convert to lower could be like "Hello hOw ARE yOU tOdAy" then i make it all to lower to make it more flexible to get the data i want to fetch but then i want to show it like "Hello hOw ARE yOU tOdAy" again.

EDIT: If anyone wonders how I solved the problem I used str_ireplace method like $a=str_ireplace("hElLo","hello",$a)

Comment: It is possible and if you put your mind to it, you'll see it's easier than you think.

Comment: Post. your php code or atleast a sample string. BTW there is a function [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) which can be used to achieve this.

Comment: It's not possible unless you store the original data. If I tell you the string `random upper case characters` is a lower-cased from some string I got then you can never know with certainty what the original string was unless I tell you.

Comment: i don't want to return the text in lowercase I want it to be the exact way it was before i modified it

Answer (score 3):

> "or does anyone have a solution?"

^ By that, I take it you might be looking for an alternate solution.

In order to keep the original value, you can assign it to a variable, and use `strtolower()` to make it lowercase, then `strtoupper()` to make it uppercase.

```
echo $original_string = "ORIGINAL UPPER CASE STRING and Camel Case or mIXed cASe";
echo "<br>";
echo $lowercased_string = strtolower($original_string) . " this has been converted.";
echo "<br>";
echo "The below is now in uppercase.";
echo "<br>";
echo $modified_string = strtoupper($original_string);
echo "<br>";

$var = $original_string . " is the original value.";
echo $var;
```

Note: Echoing an assigned variable is perfectly valid. You can remove those as needed.

The above will print:

```
ORIGINAL UPPER CASE STRING and Camel Case or mIXed cASe
original upper case string and camel case or mixed case this has been converted.
The below is now in uppercase.
ORIGINAL UPPER CASE STRING AND CAMEL CASE OR MIXED CASE
ORIGINAL UPPER CASE STRING and Camel Case or mIXed cASe is the original value.
```

Comment: What i want to do is find a string within a string like between the words"Hello" and "Bye" . but these words can be written differently, either "hello" "Hello","HELLO","hEllo" etc. if i make the whole string tolower, the text beetween those two words that i want to find and use will all be tolower,  which will be weird if a sentence start with a lower character etc.

its only because i dont want to have to write all different combinations, i want to find the word "hello" even if it is written "HELLO" or "hello" or "Hello"

Comment: @Dmitrilen that's a completely different question than what you originally posted. Start with what you've been given.

Comment: Yeah I expressed myself badly but that is my problem. I would be super thankfull if you have any clue on what to do @Fred -ii-. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this?

```
echo strtolower("THIS WILL ALL BE LOWERCASE.");
```

and for making it all cap again (upper) do

```
echo strtoupper("this will all be upper case");
```

So you can take the input as strtolower, then in your return, lets say to save to a DB, send it in a strtoupper. Hope that helps, if not please explain an example case.

Comment: Example: "Hello"
tolower = hello 
i want it to be returned as Hello not HELLO or anything like that

Comment: Thanks but not really, the data I convert to lower could be like "Hello hOw ARE yOU tOdAy" then i make it all to lower to make it more flexible to get the data i want to fetch but then i want to show it like  "Hello hOw ARE yOU tOdAy" again.

Comment: @Dmitrilen, maybe create two variables then. One to change the string to how you'd like, use it as needed for manipulation/storing. And keep the original string of text for whatever case you might need from the original text. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wonders how I solved the problem I used str_ireplace method like $a=str_ireplace("hElLo","hello",$a)